# Bundle update stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I am having troubles doing `bundle update`

It seems to get stuck on these 3 weird gems..**["spicycode-rcov", "jnunemaker-crack", "tenderlove-frex"]** I have no idea what they are for or where they came from..

this is the last few lines of `bundle update --verbose` where it gets stuck

```
Unmet Dependencies: ["spicycode-rcov", "jnunemaker-crack", "tenderlove-frex"]
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Query List: ["spicycode-rcov", "jnunemaker-crack", "tenderlove-frex"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: spicycode-rcov jnunemaker-crack tenderlove-frex
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=spicycode-rcov,jnunemaker-crack,tenderlove-frex
HTTP Success
Query List: []
```

my gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails'



gem 'pg'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable'


gem 'thin'

gem 'geocoder'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'


    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem "asset_sync"

group :development, :test do
    gem "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1", :platform => [:mswin, :mingw]

    gem 'rails-erd'
    gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0" 
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'lol_dba'
    gem "rspec-rails"
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem "guard-rspec"

end

group :test do

    gem "faker"
    gem "capybara"
    gem "database_cleaner"
    gem "launchy"


end


gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'


gem 'tinymce-rails'

gem "aws-ses", "~> 0.4.4", :require => 'aws/ses'


gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'


gem 'newrelic_rpm'
```

this is the gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.9)
      activemodel (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
    activesupport (3.2.9)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    addressable (2.3.2)
    annotate (2.5.0)
      rake
    arel (3.0.2)
    asset_sync (0.5.0)
      activemodel
      fog
    aws-sdk (1.7.1)
      httparty (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    aws-ses (0.4.4)
      builder
      mail (> 2.2.5)
      mime-types
      xml-simple
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
    bootstrap-sass-rails (2.2.1.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1)
    builder (3.0.4)
    capybara (2.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 1.0.0)
    childprocess (0.3.6)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.6)
    choice (0.1.6)
    cocaine (0.4.2)
    coderay (1.0.8)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (0.9.1)
    devise (2.1.2)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    devise_invitable (1.1.2)
      actionmailer (~> 3.0)
      devise (>= 2.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.0-x86-mingw32)
    excon (0.16.10)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.1.5-x86-mingw32)
    fog (1.7.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.14)
      formatador (~> 0.2.0)
      mime-types
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      net-scp (~> 1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)
      ruby-hmac
    formatador (0.2.4)
    geocoder (1.1.5)
    guard (1.5.4)
      listen (>= 0.4.2)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (2.1.2)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.11)
    hike (1.2.1)
    httparty (0.9.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.1.3)
      railties (>= 3.1.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jquery-ui-rails (2.0.2)
      jquery-rails
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.7.5)
    launchy (2.1.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    libwebsocket (0.1.6)
      websocket
    listen (0.5.3)
    lol_dba (1.3.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    lumberjack (1.0.2)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.1)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.7)
    multi_xml (0.5.1)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-ssh (2.6.1)
    newrelic_rpm (3.5.2.17)
    nokogiri (1.5.5-x86-mingw32)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    paperclip (3.3.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.4.0)
      mime-types
    pg (0.14.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.10-x86-mingw32)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.3.1)
      win32console (~> 1.3)
    pry-rails (0.2.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.9)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activerecord (= 3.2.9)
      activeresource (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.9)
    rails-erd (1.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      choice (~> 0.1.6)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.0.4)
    rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.10)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    railties (3.2.9)
      actionpack (= 3.2.9)
      activesupport (= 3.2.9)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.1)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.12.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.12.0)
    rspec-core (2.12.0)
    rspec-expectations (2.12.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
    rspec-mocks (2.12.0)
    rspec-rails (2.12.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.12.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.12.0)
    ruby-graphviz (1.0.8)
    ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.2.3)
    sass-rails (3.2.5)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    selenium-webdriver (2.26.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      libwebsocket (~> 0.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
    slop (3.3.3)
    sprockets (2.2.1)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thin (1.5.0)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    tinymce-rails (3.5.7.1)
      railties (>= 3.1.1)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    uuidtools (2.1.3)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket (1.0.2)
    win32console (1.3.2-x86-mingw32)
    xml-simple (1.1.2)
    xpath (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  acts-as-taggable-on (~> 2.3.1)
  annotate (>= 2.5.0)
  asset_sync
  aws-sdk
  aws-ses (~> 0.4.4)
  bootstrap-sass-rails
  capybara
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  database_cleaner
  devise
  devise_invitable
  eventmachine (~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1)
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  geocoder
  guard-rspec
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  launchy
  lol_dba
  newrelic_rpm
  paperclip
  pg
  pry-rails
  rails
  rails-erd
  rails3-jquery-autocomplete
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  thin
  tinymce-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: The gems are probably in your Gemfile.lock; you can try to delete it and regenerate it with `bundle install`

Comment: tried that... it gets stuck on install as well..

Comment: try to install those gems by hand: gem install spicycode-rcov (for each gem), maybe you have a more clear error of what happens and when you get those 3 gems installed you can run bundle again

Comment: gem install doesn't find those gems.. I don't understand where they come from.. if I google them they are really old..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is usually (almost always) a dependency issue..
something like that https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1984

it seems that the best case I can find is to go over each gem version in the last working gemfile.lock and in the gemfile specify ~> which version to install.. go one by one until everything works well..

Comment: That seems to fix it. It's been a long debug but going gem by gem I finally sorted it out. I guess some gems didn't play well together. Once I did `gem rails, "~> 3.29"` it works like a charm! thanks!